# Using NPM Registry Connection build feature in TeamCity to publish a package

Tags: node.js, npm, teamcity

In TeamCity, I have configured an "NPM Registry Connection" build feature following [this Jetbrains guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/space/publish-npm-packages.html#publish-npm-using-jetbrains-teamcity). When testing a connection for my package it gives me the "Success" message.

[image]

Then I added this connection as a build feature to my Build Configuration. I do not see any additional steps in any documentation that should be applied so I thought that, now, simply calling `npm publish` will succeed but instead I'm getting

```
[Step 5/5] npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
[Step 5/5] npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in to https://registry.npmjs.org/
[Step 5/5] npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`
```

My build configuration:

```
steps {
    script {
        name = "install"
        scriptContent = "npm ci && npm install jest-teamcity --no-save"
        formatStderrAsError = true
    }
    script {
        name = "eslint"
        scriptContent = "npm run eslint"
        formatStderrAsError = true
    }
    script {
        name = "build"
        scriptContent = "npm run clean && npx tsc"
        formatStderrAsError = true
    }
    script {
        name = "test"
        scriptContent = "npm run test -- --reporters=jest-teamcity"
        formatStderrAsError = true
    }
    script {
        name = "publish"
        scriptContent = "npm publish"
        formatStderrAsError = true
    }
}

triggers {
    vcs {
    }
}

features {
    npmRegistry {
        connectionId = "PROJECT_EXT_2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, NPM Connection build feature only works with nodejs runner. You should replace Command Line runner with NodeJS one. For more information see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-73072/Npm-connection-not-working-without-Nodejs-step

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, our TC instance doesn't have docker support so we can't use NodeJS runner. As a workaround, I used `.npmrc` file with the token environment variable which I set in TC parameters.